# Not apply the same function to all rows of a Pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I want to extact the first `3` from values of a pandas column without doing a loop.

So,

```
df['myCol'][3]
5475
```

In order to extract the first 3 digits I do:

```
int(str(df['myCol'][3])[:2])
547
```

I want to apply to all the same procedure to the entire column. How can I do it?

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need select by indexing with [`str[]`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) and then cast to `integer`s:

```
df['myCol'].str[:2].astype(int)
```

If input values are integers, first cast to `string`s:

```
df['myCol'].astype(str).str[:2].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have a numeric column:

```
In [189]: df
Out[189]:
    myCol
0    5475
1   99999
2  123456

In [190]: df.dtypes
Out[190]:
myCol    int64
dtype: object

In [191]: df['myCol'] // 10**(np.log10(df.myCol).astype(int) - 2)
Out[191]:
0    547
1    999
2    123
Name: myCol, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like playing with `format` this one also does the job:

```
df['myCol'].map(lambda x: '{:.3}'.format(str(x)))
```